# Pandas: assign to column with map

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':["a","aa","aaaaa","a"]})
df["len"] = map(len, df["a"])
```

Why does this not work? Or rather, why is this not supposed to work?

I understand that `list(map(...))` works, and I understand that Pandas would need to provide the functionality to do `df["col"] = map(...)`

I wonder more why this was not implemented / why this wouldn't be considered Pythonic / Pandaesque.

Comment: map() does not work as function with pandas because pandas already has map as its method. You can call directly with data frame and pass len() or any other function you want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder more why this was not implemented / why this wouldn't be considered Pythonic /

I think answer is - because already exist method [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), so in pandas `map` working different like pure python.

Btw, here is better use pandas version for lengths - [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
df["len"] = df["a"].str.len()
```

but also working if use pandas `map` method:

```
df["len"] = df["a"].map(len)
```